# Find out the camera picture location

Tags: android, android-camera

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/Camera"
```

I tried this code for find the location of camera storage images but its give only "DCIM" image location.but some devices not store always in "DCIM" folder so how could i find out storage location?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Comment: its give all images of device but I want to read only camera images.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to below code work for my app perfect :-**

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
```

**Method:-**

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
    {
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..but we don't take image from our app ,we only want to read  camera images.

Comment: File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME); can you use this IMAGE _DIRECTORY_NAME is your folder name

Comment: i think, i have to give the name of   IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME  in this code but , i don't want to give the name manually. according to my need,find  out camera storage  images location. but some devices not contain camera images in DCIM folder. so how could i find out in every devices...?